# Xbox 360 is backwards compatible for Yu-Gi-Oh: Dawn of Destiny, but the game won't start

Tags: xbox-360, backwards-compatibility

Whilst doing some research about backwards compatiblity on the Xbox 360, I found one of my favorite games from the original Xbox, *Yu-Gi-Oh The Dawn of Destiny*, was backwards compatible. I found a small game shop in town that had this game so I proceeded to buy it.

I inspected the disc before purchasing, there are no noticeable scratches, scuffs, or anything else that would indicate a problem - the disc is very clean, great!

I inserted the game into my Xbox 360 and went to play it but no such luck. Here is the exact error I am getting:

[image: The text says "Game Error: The game couldn't start. Try downloading the game again.]

- My console is completely up to date
- I have plenty of space on my memory cards and hard drive for any save files.

**Is there some hardware requirement for backwards compatibility to work correctly? Or is it only certain models of Xbox/hard drives that provide backwards compatibility?** I'm about to go all "office space" on my Xbox if I can't figure this out.

Comment: What actual error do you get?

Comment: @James  I'm not in front of my system since I'm at work, but I believe it said something "unable to play disc" or something like "Game Error. The game could not start." I could be wrong but can get exact verbiage when I get home.

Comment: Sorry, only info I could find in relationship to this is that it also requires your harddrive be an official 360 hard drive. Aside from that you crossed everything else on their FAQ sheet off the list. I have not found a version where the 360 dropped backwards compatibility like the PS3 did.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to be the bearer of bad news (3ish years late) but only certain models of Xbox 360 allow backwards compatibility with Xbox Original games.  I believe the newer slim black ones and certain Arcade Edition Xbox 360's will allow for backwards compatibility.  You might have one of the Xbox 360's that did not come with a HDD (Hard Disc Drive) and therefore cannot take advantage of backwards compatibility. (See [List of Xbox 360 retail configurations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Xbox_360_retail_configurations))  I hope this helps!